# Trouble using Simple Form on a rails starter project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm getting the following error while trying to create a form, `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class`

This project of mine is to capture my ideas. I could use a google doc but figured this should be easy enough to try and code an app for myself. Below is the code as I think it should be from what I read on the simple form site in my newopp.html.erb (in my opps view folder.

I created a controller and a model and I am certain part of my problem is the fact that I can't figure out what I need to code or what to add for code to properly complete this step. All the tutorials I have looked at gave me a couple ideas to play with and try to make work to no avail.

So basically I am sitting on a rails generated controller named opps_controller.rb and a model called opp.rb. Both of these are nothing more than what the generator provided since I had to go back to square one

Simple form code that I have started with

```
<%= simple_form_for @opp do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :subtitle %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :idea %>
  <%= f.input :added %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

opp.rb file

```
class Opp < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :added, :description, :idea, :subtitle, :title
end
```

If it makes a difference, I have migrated the database, I ran the simple form install script with the bootstrap configuration. I'm using `rails 3.2.9` and `ruby 1.9.3p362` (2012-12-25 revision 38607) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]

As I mentioned I just have a blank controller that was created using a generator and I need to get the CRUD functionality working. Everything I have tried has failed at this point. I appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Would you add your code in your controller for the new method? So this would be app/controllers/opps_controller and the `def new` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be `newopp.html.erb`, just `new.html.erb`. So the path would be `/views/opps/new.html.erb`

If you're still getting an error then make sure `@opp` is defined in the controller:

```
class OppsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @opp = Opp.new
  end

  def create
    @opp = Opp.new
    if @opp.update_attributes(params[:opp])
      ...
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```